# Copy one table data and insert those to another table in the same database using JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, copy

I want to select some data from one MYSQL database table and insert those selected data to another table in the same database using JAVA. Both tables have the same structure. So far i can select data, but i cannot insert those data.

**test** and **test_t** are the tables.

**item_id** is the only column in the table.

I also want to delete **test** table data after I inserted them to the **test_t** table. This test table is like a temporary table.

This is my method.

```
private void testM() throws Exception {

        pooler = DBPool_SF.getInstance();
        dataSource = pooler.getDataSource();
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        PreparedStatement ps,ps1 = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String SEL_QUERY = "select item_id from test";
        String UPDATE_QUERY = "insert into test_t values(?)";

        ps = con.prepareStatement(SEL_QUERY);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ps1 = con.prepareStatement(UPDATE_QUERY );

        while (rs.next()) {

            String id = rs.getString("item_id");
            System.out.println(id);
             ps1.setString(1,id);
             ps1.addBatch();
            }

            ps1.executeBatch();
        con.close();
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or any other hint of something going wrong? Besides that why don't you do that on the database using [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: before close connection use commit.                                  con.close();con.commit();

Comment: @thomas - thankz and sorry for my delay reply.i was unable to reach.by the way,i am not getting any error..because i am using a RFC to connect with the SAP. For that i need to have temporary table and backup table.i am processig data using temporary table(test) to SAP and put that into the backup table(test_t). Then delete temp.. table

Comment: @user5478656 - i am not getting any error.

Comment: @prasath - ok i wil try.thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will work. If you mention setAutoCommit(false), then you need commit at the end.

```
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement ps, ps1 = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Statement st = null;

        String SEL_QUERY = "select item_id from test";
        String UPDATE_QUERY = "insert into test_t values(?)";
        String DELETE_QUERY = "delete from test";

        st = con.createStatement();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(SEL_QUERY);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        ps1 = con.prepareStatement(UPDATE_QUERY);

        while (rs.next())
        {

            String id = rs.getString("item_id");
            System.out.println(" item_id : " + id);
            ps1.setString(1, id);
            ps1.addBatch();
        }

        ps1.executeBatch();
        st.execute(DELETE_QUERY);

        con.commit();
        con.close();
```